# Query that return unbooked rooms

Tags: mysql, sql

For a project, I've built a hotel database (mysql) to manage bookings.

I am trying to create a query that will return a list of rooms NOT booked within a specific time range.

Here is the reservation table

```
idReservation    checkinDate    checkoutDate     idUser
```

Here is the room table

```
id room    pricePerNight    imgRoom    roomSize   



SELECT room.*    
FROM room    
LEFT JOIN reservation    
ON room.idRoom = reservation.idRoom    
AND reservation.checkin <= '2022-05-01'    
AND reservation.checkout > '2022-05-10'    
WHERE reservation.id IS NULL
```

I expect it to return a certain number of rooms, but currently it only returns rooms that have no bookings recorded.

The query result is not correct.

Can someone help me understand the error?

I think it might be in the AND clauses, but I don't understand how I should modify it.

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide sample data and wanted result, i am strugeling, why there is a reservation with no room , but with data and user

Comment: Something missing here - surely rooms must potentially be available for a date range but may be reserved for all or part of that range..in which case you need to generate room/potentially available and then test against reserved,

Answer (score 0):

These solutions/explanations assume that you allow for check in on the same day that the previous occupant checks out.

One approach to solve this is to find all possible conflicts and then negate them with LEFT JOIN IS NULL. So, if we take this chart of conflicts as a starting point -

[image]

The conflict with `Res 1` is found with -

```
checkin <= '2022-05-01' AND checkout > '2022-05-01'
```

The conflict with `Res 2` is found with -

```
checkin < '2022-05-10' AND checkout >= '2022-05-10'
```

The conflict with `Res 4` meets the criteria of both `Res 1` and `Res 2` so does not need another set of criteria.

The conflict with `Res 4` is found with -

```
checkin >= '2022-05-01' AND checkout <= '2022-05-10'
```

`Room 5` has no conflict as `Res 5` checks out on the day we want to check in and `Res 6` checks in on the day we want to check out.

Putting the above criteria together we end up with -

```
SELECT rm.*    
FROM room rm
LEFT JOIN reservation res
    ON rm.idRoom = res.idRoom
    AND (
        (checkin <= '2022-05-01' AND checkout > '2022-05-01') OR
        (checkin < '2022-05-10' AND checkout >= '2022-05-10') OR
        (checkin >= '2022-05-01' AND checkout <= '2022-05-10')
    )
WHERE res.id IS NULL;
```

Another way to find `conflicts` is to look for `not(no conflict)`. So, for there to be no overlap the existing reservation must end before the start of the requested period or start after the end of it -

```
NOT(res.checkin >= '2022-05-10' OR res.checkout <= '2022-05-01')
```

As `not (A or B) = (not A) and (not B)` ([De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)) this can be rewritten as -

```
NOT(res.checkin >= '2022-05-10') AND NOT(res.checkout <= '2022-05-01')
```

Which, with the negations applied to the comparison operators, becomes -

```
res.checkin < '2022-05-10' AND res.checkout > '2022-05-01'
```

Putting it all together we end up with -

```
SELECT rm.*    
FROM room rm
LEFT JOIN reservation res
    ON rm.idRoom = res.idRoom
    AND res.checkin < '2022-05-10'
    AND res.checkout > '2022-05-01'
WHERE res.id IS NULL;
```